# Is it possible to ignore the insert when integrated reference occurs but insert the other records?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, ado.net

I have a N:N relationship between two tables, so I have a link table to connect them both. The PK of this link table is the combination of the two PK of both tables. This is the basic.

I want to related many records, so in my application I use a loop to create my command that is like that:

```
begin transaction
insert into MyMiddleTable(ID1, ID2) VALUES(1, 2);
insert into MyMiddleTable(ID1, ID2) VALUES(1, 3);
...
commit;
```

But if one of the records that I want to related is deleted by other process in the middle of the transaction, then I get an error of reference integrity, that is ok, but then it does not create any of the others relations that could be created because the other records exist.

So my question is if there is some way to say to SQL Server that this reference integrity occurs with one pair of registers, ignore the and continue with the next and create all of the relations that can be created. Because if one record does not exist because it was deleted I don't create this relation, but the the others I want to.

Fore example, when I try to delete a relationship that it was deleted in the middle of the process SQL Server notify this event, but continue and delete the rest of the relationships. It's true that in my code, in the case of the delete is not in a transaction, but I try to do the insert without a transaction and the problem persists.

I know that other solution could be block the two main tables with a hint table, but I would like to avoid to block both tables for created this relations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not wrap the whole thing in a transaction:

<del>begin transaction</del>

```
insert into MyMiddleTable(ID1, ID2) VALUES(1, 2);
insert into MyMiddleTable(ID1, ID2) VALUES(1, 3);
...
```

<del>commit;</del>

You're explicitly telling SQL to fail if any one of those things fails.  When you say that the problem persists when it is not in a transaction, from what program are you executing this SQL?  If you are in SSMS you may need to separate each statement with a GO or something otherwise you may be getting implicit transaction that encompasses all of the statements still.

Answer (score 1):

What needs to occur here is removing that loop process and working on a set based method to commit the records to the link table as part of one transaction. There's not enough information here to really provide specific logic, but here's an example.

Please note the DISTINCT to prevent the duplicate inserts and the LEFT JOIN to eliminate existing values from the insert set.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('LeftTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE LeftTable
IF OBJECT_ID('RightTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE RightTable
IF OBJECT_ID('BridgeTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE BridgeTable
CREATE TABLE LeftTable (LeftID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, LeftValue UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);
CREATE TABLE RightTable (RightID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, RightValue UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);
CREATE TABLE BridgeTable (LeftID INT NOT NULL, RightID INT NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE BridgeTable ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_BridgeTable_LeftIDRightID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LeftID], [RightID]);

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LeftTable) < 100
INSERT INTO LeftTable (LeftValue) SELECT NEWID()

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RightTable) < 100
INSERT INTO RightTable (RightValue) SELECT NEWID()

--Replace with actual matching logic
;WITH cteJoinSet AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT L.LeftID, R.RightID
    FROM LeftTable L
    CROSS JOIN RightTable R
)

INSERT INTO BridgeTable (LeftID, RightID)
SELECT J.LeftID, J.RightID
FROM cteJoinSet J
LEFT JOIN BridgeTable B ON B.LeftID = J.LeftID
    AND B.RightID = J.RightID
WHERE B.LeftID IS NULL
```